# Text file opening in python

Tags: python

Could someone give me some guidance on how you would get the contents of your text file on my python code without opening up the text file in another window?
Just point me in the right direction on how I should do it (No need for solutions)

Comment: Con you be more specific with your question? You want to read contents of a file in your python code?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: You want to include the contents of a text file in a Python script so that the script can process the text?

Comment: Refer this - [Reading and Writing files](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open("your_file.txt", "r")
file.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(workfile, 'r') as f:
   for line in f:
      print line
```

If you don't use the context manager (the with statement) you will need to explicitly call f.close(), for example:

```
f = open('workfile', 'r')
line = f.readline()
print line
f.close()
```